# Forms - Drawing from external class

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

I'm looking for a way to draw to a form from an external class. The way I worked out by myself is passing the Graphics object from the OnPaint PaintEventArgs in the constructor of my external class:

```
     public void DrawBezier(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
     {
        PointF point1 = new PointF(10, 300);
        PointF point2 = new PointF(180, 50);
        PointF point3 = new PointF(320, 300);

        Pen blackpen = new Pen (Color.Black, 2);
        Pen redpen = new Pen (Color.Red, 2);

        Bezier mybezier = new Bezier (point1, point2, point3, e.Graphics);
   }
```

- ```
  public Bezier (Graphics graphics)
  {
      this.bezierGraphics = graphics;
  }

  private void drawLine(Pen pen, PointF p1, PointF p2)
  {
      this.bezierGraphics.DrawLine (pen, p1, p2);
  }
  ```

Is this an acceptable practice? Are there any other approaches I could have taken to solve the problem? Or is the approach of trying to draw from an external class not sensible at all?

I realize the question is rather broad, but all the examples I found on the net so far simply call all graphics functions in the class that is straight out inheriting from forms.

Comment: Not sure it is a good idea to keep around a disposable object like Graphics.

Comment: It's OK to place drawing logic in some external classes. From this point form or any other control is just a drawing surface provider. You may draw the same way on another surface, e.g. bitmap.

Comment: As soon as the lifetime of your class is limited to `OnPaint` event, there is no problem.

Comment: Your constructor doesn't seem to match your paint code.  Don't forget to dispose of your Pens.

Comment: @LarsTech: Thanks, I noticed and fixed that already. I'll keep disposing of Pens in mind.

Comment: Ivan nails it!! Do not try to keep the Graphics object around, it really shouldn't be cached!